# Is there a way to for an object filter to pass the object without a named reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following javascript code which produces the desired results, i.e. returns both the 3rd and 4th objects in objectsArray since they both contain the max distance. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to not have to retype the name of the array when calling **objectsArray.filter**? I'm not trying to be lazy, just avoiding redundancy and the possibility of introducing a typo.

```
function meetsMax(obj) {

    return obj.distance === Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(o) { return o.distance; }));
}

const objectsArray = [{ "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" }];

const objMax = objectsArray.filter(meetsMax, objectsArray);

console.log("objMax:", objMax);
```

I certainly wouldn't mind any other pointers on making the code more efficient and performant.

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.filter()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(o) { return o.distance; }))` easier: `this.reduce((c,i)=>Math.max(c,i))` and better execute `Math.max(c,i)` before the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function calls in JavaScript have some overhead, so native code is more efficient and performant:

```js
var a = [ { "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, 
          { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" } ]

for (var o = a[0], objMax = [o], m = o.distance, d, i = 1; i < a.length; i++) 
    if ((d = (o = a[i]).distance) > m) { objMax = [o]; m = d }
    else if (d === m) objMax[objMax.length] = o

console.log(JSON.stringify(objMax))
```

---

There are also shorter and less efficient alternatives:

```js
var a = [ { "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, 
          { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" } ]

var d, b = []; a.forEach(o => (b[d = o.distance] = b[d] || []).push(o))

console.log(JSON.stringify(b[b.length - 1]))
```

Comment: After running performance tests on almost all the answers (as of this writing), I found the first of these most performant (~30X faster than next best). In fact, writing a "min" version, performance was even better.

Comment: I was expecting it to be about the same as @zhuravlyov's second version. The difference can vary a lot between different browsers, but another big advantage is that it can work on older browsers that don't support ES5 methods.

Comment: Both @zhuravlyov's 2nd and this work in Chrome, IE II, Edge, and Firefox. Across the board, this is much faster. In IE/Edge it's faster than Chrome or Firefox while the other method is really slow. In Chrome or FF, this is ~10X faster. I'll mostly use this in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use for loop? It will be faster than your code.

```js
"use strict";

let start = performance.now();
for (let z = 0; z < 1000; z++) {
    function meetsMax(obj) {

        return obj.distance === Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(o) { return o.distance; }));
    }

    const objectsArray = [{ "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" }];

    const objMax = objectsArray.filter(meetsMax, objectsArray);
}
let fin = performance.now() - start;
console.log(fin); // 3.25ms
```

```js
"use strict";

let start = performance.now();
for (let z = 0; z < 1000; z++) {
    let a = [{ "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" }];
    let maxDistance = 0;
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0, max = a.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (a[i].distance > maxDistance) {
            maxDistance = a[i].distance;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0, max = a.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (a[i].distance === maxDistance) {
            result.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
let fin = performance.now() - start;
console.log(fin); // 1.28ms
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter` passes three arguments to the array: the current value, the index of the current value and the array itself. So you can change your filter function to:

```
function meetsMax(obj, index, objectsArray) {

    return obj.distance === Math.max.apply(Math, objectsArray.map(function(o) { return o.distance; }));
}
```

and call `.filter` with

```
 objectsArray.filter(meetsMax);
```

---

Always [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of the functions you are using.

---

> I certainly wouldn't mind any other pointers on making the code more efficient and performant.

If you, compute the maximum distance only once instead of in every iteration of the array. E.g. you could do:

```
function filterMax(arr, extractor) {
    const max = arr.reduce(function(max, item) {
      return max < extractor(item) ? extractor(item) : max;
    }, extractor(arr[0]));
    return arr.filter(function(item) {
      return extractor(item) === max;
    });
}
```

and call it as

```
filterMax(objectsArray, function(obj) { return obj.distance; });
```

```js
function filterMax(arr, extractor) {
  const max = arr.reduce(function(max, item) {
    return max < extractor(item) ? extractor(item) : max;
  }, extractor(arr[0]));
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return extractor(item) === max;
  });
}

const objectsArray = [{ "distance": 1, "name": "first" }, { "distance": 2, "name": "second" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "third" }, { "distance": 3, "name": "fourth" }];

console.log(filterMax(objectsArray, function(obj) {
  return obj.distance;
}));
```

Comment: While this answers the question for the filtering, it doesn't address the performance issue - the current filter is very wasteful, the target array is mapped on each iteration. It would be much cheaper to reduce the whole array in one go.

Comment: The last line of the question asks for _"pointers on making the code more efficient and performant"_. That's pretty straight forward asking about performance.

Comment: Performance on this was really good (.09 ms on my machine) and I like its generic structure.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN's `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), the array name is an optional override to the internal value of `this`.

So to answer the original question:

> I'm wondering if there is a way to not have to retype the name of the array when calling objectsArray.filter?

Yes, you can safely leave it out.

```
var filter = function(x) { if (x > 5) return true; };
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
alert(arr.filter(filter).join(","));
```

or even simpler (albeit harder to read):

```
alert([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].filter(function(x) { if (x > 5) return true; }));
```

You specifically asked about an `object`, but you're not filtering objects, you're filtering an **array of objects**, so same applies.

```
console.log([ {foo: 1}, {foo: 2}, {foo: 3}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}, {foo: 6}, {foo: 7}, {foo: 8}, {foo: 9}, {foo: 10}].filter(function(x) { if (x.foo > 5) return true; }));
```